# Syncing AIDE and apt-get

Tags: apt, aide

I would like to run AIDE from a stick on a system. However there is a major difficulty. Apt-get will modify files in particular with commands update, install, remove/purge which will muck up the AIDE database.

I would like to generate a list of modified files which I can use to update the AIDE database.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which distribution are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Debian, the default AIDE installation offers configuration options to exclude changes from package and security updates.

From `/etc/default/aide`,

```
# Set this to yes to suppress file changes by package and security
# updates from appearing in the e-mail report. Filtered file changes will
# still be listed in the log file. This option parses the /var/log/dpkg.log
# file and implies TRUNCATEDETAILS=yes
FILTERUPDATES=yes
```

Which is used in `/etc/cron.daily/aide` to filter information by parsing `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

There's no single switch or simple config file within AIDE that will do it, as far as I can tell, so you'll need to build the excludes manually.

I suggest using the Debian `aide` script as the basis for your solution.